# Notification is not canceling after click the notification android using GCM

Tags: android, remoteview

> Notification send method in helper class

```
public static void createAndSendNotification(Context context, String title, int id, String text, PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent) {
    NotificationTarget mNotificationTarget;
      RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.remoteview_notification_updated);
    // Bundle bndle = new Bundle();
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Random randomizer = new Random();
    String pathforCategories = context.getSharedPreferences
        (Constants.PACKAGE_NAME, 0).getString(Constants.DEFAULT_PATH, "")+title+"/" ;
    Log.v("path_check", pathforCategories);

    File f = new File(pathforCategories);
    // List<File> filesL
    File[] filesList = f.listFiles();
    Log.v("reached", "here");
    String type = new String();
    HashMap <String,String> hm = new HashMap<>();
      Gson gson = new Gson();
      hm =gson.fromJson(context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.PACKAGE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE).
              getString("textForNotification",""),HashMap.class);
      Log.v("checkhm",hm+"");

    List<File> filesAll = new ArrayList<>() ;
    try {
      filesAll = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(filesList));
    }
    catch (NullPointerException ne)
    {
      Crashlytics.logException(ne);
    }

    Log.v("filessizw",String.valueOf(filesAll.size())+"si");
//    Log.v("files",f.listFiles().toString()+"si2");
    List<File> filesImages = new ArrayList<>();
    if (filesAll.size() != 0) {
      Log.v("1", "1");
      for (int i = 0; i < filesAll.size(); i++) {

        String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(filesAll.get(i).getAbsolutePath());
        Log.v("ext",extension);
        if (extension.equalsIgnoreCase("jpg")) {
          filesImages.add(filesAll.get(i));
        }
        //       filesImages.get(i).del(ete();
        else if (extension.equalsIgnoreCase("jpeg")) {
          Log.v("1", "1");
          filesImages.add(filesAll.get(i));
        } else if (extension.equalsIgnoreCase("png")) {
          Log.v("3", "3");
          filesImages.add(filesAll.get(i));
        }
        else if (extension.equalsIgnoreCase("jpgm"))
        {

          Log.v("3", "3");
          filesImages.add(filesAll.get(i));
        }


      }
      //filesImages.notify();
      Log.v("size images array", String.valueOf(filesImages.size()));
      if (filesImages.size() != 0) {
        File random = filesImages.get(randomizer.nextInt(filesImages.size()));





        String realPath = random.getAbsolutePath();
        File targetFile;
        Uri uri;
        try {
          String pathfForImage = realPath;
          /*  String pathfForImage =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                    File.separator + "Camera"+File.separator+"er.PNG";*/
          targetFile = new File(pathfForImage);
          ;
          Log.v("name for file", targetFile.getName());
          uri = Uri.fromFile(targetFile);
          Log.v("value of uri b", uri.toString());

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
          Crashlytics.logException(e);
          targetFile = new File("");
          uri = Uri.fromFile(f);
          Log.v("value of uri b", uri.toString());
        }
          Log.v("check_valueafter fetch",targetFile.getName().substring(6,10));
       // Log.v("check_valueafter fetch",hm.get(uri.toString().substring(6,10)));
//        rv.setTextViewText(R.id.txt_notification_headline, hm.get(uri.toString().substring(uri.toString().length()-5)));
     //   rv.setTextViewText(R.id.txt_notification_headline, "Reminder for Common Quotes");
        //   rv.setTextViewText(R.id.txt_notification_detail, text )
        //  rv.setImageViewResource(R.id.remoteview_notification_icon, R.mipmap.launcher);
        Log.v("value of title", title);
        Log.v("value of txt", text + id);
        Log.v("value of uri af", uri.toString());
          String textNotificationget=targetFile.getName().substring(6, 10); ;

          try {
              if (hm.containsKey(targetFile.getName().substring(6, 10))) {


              }
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              ex.getMessage() ;
          }
          hm.get(textNotificationget) ;
          try {
              rv.setTextViewText(R.id.txt_notification_headline, hm.get(textNotificationget));
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              rv.setTextViewText(R.id.txt_notification_headline, "Common Quotes");
          }
          try {
              rv.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.remoteview_notification_icon,MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), uri));
```

// using remote view for notifications

```
          }
          catch(IOException ex)
          {
              ex.printStackTrace();
          }

      //  rv.setImageViewUri(R.id.remoteview_notification_icon, uri);
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        // rv.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.remoteview_notification_icon, BitmapFactory.decodeFile(targetFile.getAbsolutePath(),bmOptions));
        //   rv.setImageViewBitmap();
     /*   NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
               *//* .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
       .setContentTitle(title)*//*
        .setContentText(text+id);
     final Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();*/
```

> Notification Code

```
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Content Title")
                .setContentText("Content Text").setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContent(rv).setAutoCancel(true);
```

> Notification Code

```
        final Notification notification = mBuilder.build();

       // notification.
          mNotificationTarget = new NotificationTarget(
                  context,
                  rv,
                  R.id.remoteview_notification_icon,
                  notification,
                  id);
       /*   try {
              Glide
                      .with(context.getApplicationContext()) // safer!
                      .load(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), uri))
                      .asBitmap()
                      .into(mNotificationTarget);

          }
          catch(IOException ex)
          {
              ex.printStackTrace();
          }*/

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
          notification.bigContentView = rv;
        }






      //  rv.setViewVisibility(R.layout.remoteview_notification, View.GONE);
        Log.v("code reached", "No");
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent);

        Log.v("code reached", "Yes");



        //NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        try {
          rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.linearlayout_remote_view, pendingNotificationIntent);
          Log.v("checknotifyActivity","yes");

        } catch (Exception e) {
          Crashlytics.logException(e);

        }
//          mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        mNotificationManager.notify(id, notification);




      } else {
        //                Constants.showToastMessage(context, "There are no image files in selected path ");
        // Log.v("check notifications", )
      }



      // mNotificationManager.cancel(id);
    }
    else {
     // Constants.showToastMessage(context, "There are no  files in selected path ");

    }



  }
```

> GCM service pending intent
>
> Calling pending intent here

```
 Intent intentAction = new Intent(this, QuotesListActivity.class);
      intentAction.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntentGCM = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
          1, intentAction, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

> A quick help will be appreciated
>
> Thanks in advance